# JavaFX: Labels in VBox getting overlapped

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm creating a video analysis system. At the moment I'm working on the player itself, using JavaFX. Next to my player, I want to have a list of marks placed during the analysis (see picture).

**How I want it:**
[image: How I want it]

**But then it overlaps...**
[image: But then it overlaps...]

**Until it gets to this:**
[image: Until it gets to this]

The list is getting created inside a VBox inside a ScrollPane. I've already considered using Text objects instead of Label objects, but I really want to use labels because I need to use their background property.

**This code reproduces my problem:**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    final Button button = new Button("Click me!");
    final VBox vb = new VBox();
    final ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(vb);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        VBox v = new VBox();
        v.getChildren().addAll(button, sp);
        root.getChildren().add(v);

        sp.setFitToHeight(true);
        sp.setFitToWidth(true);
        sp.setMaxHeight(150);
        sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                addButton();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void addButton() {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: null");
        btn.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
        String text = "Time: 00:00\nIt's very late!";
        btn.setText(text);
        btn.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #87CEFA");
            }
        });
        btn.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: null");
            }
        });
        btn.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        Separator sep = new Separator();
        vb.getChildren().addAll(btn, sep);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really quite difficult to answer as it is pretty unclear what is going on without [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Some possibly unrelated comments:  Why use a clickable label rather than a button?  Why base positioning of the line based upon translation rather than layout properties?  Why use a line at all rather than a Separator?  Setting line startX and startY based on label height is strange.  The controls shouldn't squish up like that unless you placed some constraints on the scroll pane, scroll pane area or some other container or node set that you aren't showing.

Comment: @jewelsea Okay, the line is indeed a weird one to use... still learning haha. I changed the objects into buttons but then they still squish up. What information do you need from me to get a better picture?

Comment: Supply an mcve.  Read the link provided.  An mcve is minimal and complete code that only replicates the issue (e.g. it wouldn't need any video control or anything like that, only a stand-alone application with a bunch of buttons in a ScrollPane that scrunch up) and somebody could copy and paste to run and replicate the issue.

Comment: @jewelsea I added an mcve. Let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you fit the height of the content of the ScrollPane to the height of the ScrollPane's viewport.  Don't do this.  Remove the following line:

```
sp.setFitToHeight(true);
```

Comment: Yes, this works. In addition I had to remove all the size properties of the VBox in my original project. Thanks!